# Why can not be php file run, which I located in the theme folder

Tags: php, wordpress

My page in wordpress have a button like "Go to the next".

I am trying to get my php file run by clicking the button.

```
<form action="https://"domain name".com/hoge.php" method="POST"></form>
```

The php file is successfully run if I locate the php file in the domain.
(like, https://"domain name".com/hoge.php)

However, the php file can not be run if I locate the file in the themes folder, and the response is 404 not found.
(like, https://"domain name".com/public_html/wp-content/themes/hoge.php)

So I have 2 questions.

1. Why the php file can not be accessed if I locate the file in the themes folder?
2. Talking about security, is it safe to locate my php file in the domain directly?
   (like, https://"domain name".com/hoge.php)

Comment: Well does the file exist in that folder? Coz a 404 errors mean php can't find the file i.e. it does not exist at the location specified, I'm not qualified to answer question I'm sure some one with vast knowledge will be able to answer it but my opinion is that it should be safe

Comment: Question 1: There has a lot factor affecting to located your file. It might involved to the RewriteRule for .htaccess configuration, your platform configuration or just you create file at wrong location or wrong name.

Comment: Question 2: yes, it is unsafe, because it can be access by anyone else. So you need to perform some authenticate checking before execute the written code, for example use SESSION to check the user is already logged in before execute your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for question 1:

There has a lot factor affecting to located your file. It might involved to the RewriteRule for .htaccess configuration, your platform configuration or just you create file at wrong location or wrong name

### Answer for question 2:

Yes, it is unsafe, because it can be access by anyone else. So you need to perform some authenticate checking before execute the written code, for example use SESSION to check the user is already logged in before execute your code.

Answer (score 3):

wp-content implies this is a WordPress Site.

Wordpress changes the .htaccess to prevent exactly this.  The htaccess will not let you access the sub php files directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of handling **FORM** is perfectly ok, while developing in core PHP. But, WordPress has its own handling **FORM**. YOu can check out [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/) blog on how to handle the FORM in WordPress way.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Tyam Mention not.